# Create user with a blank password

Tags: lubuntu, password

How do I create a user with a blank password in Lubuntu? It seems that a password with a certain length is required when you create a new user. How do I avoid that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you want a user without a password? That's just asking for trouble specially if this machine is on the Internet or a network. Why not setup a password for the user but have them auto-login.  If you still want to have that done, then just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo useradd <user_name>
sudo passwd -d <user_name>
```

To enable auto-login, create the user, type in a password, and check Don't ask for password on login.

[image]

Comment: My children don't need a password on our 'shared' computer. They don't have administrator privileges. They just use it for games.

Comment: I guess that would be OK.

Comment: On Ubuntu Mate 20.4 this will still ask for the password when switching users because it locks the screen.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but not as easy as you may think. Normally, a user without password can not login on a Linux system. So you have to set a password hash which maches an empty string.

Have a look at this [discussion](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-add-an-user-without-password-204674/page2.html) to learn how to do it. Short answer is to put `U6aMy0wojraho` for the hash of the blank password in `/etc/passwd`, like `TheUsersName:U6aMy0wojraho:`...

Answer (score 1):

**Create an user with empty password**

```
sudo useradd test-user-0
echo test-user-0:U6aMy0wojraho | sudo chpasswd -e
su test-user-0
```

The password prompt still shows unfortunately.

But if you just hit enter without typing anything, and it logins as the user `test-user-0`.

The `-e` flags tells `chpasswd` that the password is already encrypted, and `U6aMy0wojraho` is the hash of the empty string.

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

**BusyBox autologin**

On the terminal at least, you don't need to create an user without a password to allow someone to not type their passwords everytime, hacking `inittab` a bit is enough: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299408/how-to-login-automatically-without-typing-the-root-username-or-password-in-build