# I want to make a user without password requirement

Tags: users, user-management, username, adduser

so I have ubuntu 18.4 loaded on my laptop and I have my own user on it I want to make another user without root privilege for normal use of my family which is accessible without any password. I tied to find it on google but nothing came up. how can I accomplish this

Comment: Google? How about [the documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-help/user-add.html)?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson there is no information on how to let the new user login without pasword

Comment: Sorry, missed that "without any password". Found [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/02/enable-passwordless-login-ubuntu-18-04/).

Comment: @DineshThakur, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/446818/create-user-with-a-blank-password